# javascript send cross domain form request

Tags: javascript, html, http

I want to send a cross domain post request through javascript,

Exactly how a html form sends a cross domain post request.

like this

```
<form action="http://example.com/default/en_US/ussd_info.html?type=ussd" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="john" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

so, how do I send the same request through javascript?

Comment: So what is the issue? Does the api support CORS?

Comment: yes. it supports.

Comment: So what is the issue? It is unclear what your problem is.

Comment: And you removed the Ajax call? I think you want an Ajax tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla JS you would be using XMLHttpRequests or the Fetch API. Using Fetch, The code might look something like:

```
const formElem = document.getElementById('your-form-id');

fetch('http://example.com/default/en_US/ussd_info.html?type=ussdn', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new FormData(formElem),
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: how do i send the form data through this? like html form sends the form data.

Comment: you can use the [FormData](https://javascript.info/formdata) object. I also updated the response to use the more concise Fetch API